# how to change the type of number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help change the type number double -> int. ie I need to drop the fractional part, but do not use split ()

```
import time

date = time.ctime(int('1223.435'.split('.')[0]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to float, then convert to int.

```
>>> int(float('1223.435'))
1223
```

Answer (score 0):

Partition number string by dot character:

```
import time

date = time.ctime(int('1223.435'.partition('.')[0]))
```